# Обработка исключений в golang

Tags: golang

Как обработать исключение в go?

Есть код

```
Message.Send(ActiveClients[input].websocket, string(ans.Message))
```

Если вместо `input` подставить либо строчное значение, либо не существующее числовое, то программа вылетает.

Как это обработать?

Comment: Настоятельно не рекомендую в будущем задавать один и тот же вопрос на разных ресурсах! Вот вами же заданный вопрос: https://toster.ru/q/211195. Да, он немного по-другому выражен, но имея необходимую базу Вы бы его не задавали.

Answer (score 6):

Согласно философии языка Go в нем нет исключений. В [Error handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) . Об этом документе Вам уже сообщал @VladD. Настоятельно рекомендую послушать его ;)

Сообщать об ошибках нужно так:

- Фатальные ошибки с помощью фунции panic(), востановить можно с помощью recover()
- Не фатальные с помощью возвращаемого значения в последнем параметре.

Настоятельно не рекомендую использовать panic по поводу и без повода. Другими словами почитайте статью и Вам будет понятно, какой подход по обработки принят в Go

Answer (score 1):

В Go [нет исключений](https://golang.org/doc/faq#exceptions). Возвращайте коды ошибки, где надо. Есть даже [специальный тип](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) для этого.

Использование неверного индекса — не исключение, это ошибка времени выполнения. Даже в языках, в которых есть `IndexOutOfRangeException`, ловить такое исключение считается дурным тоном. Неправильный индекс — не исключительная ситуация, а грубая ошибка. Такого просто не должно случаться в отлаженном коде.

Answer (score -1):

```
defer func() {
  if e := recover(); e != nil {
    err, ok := e.(error)
    if !ok {
      err = errors.New(e.(string))
    }
    // тут обрабатывай исключение сколько душе угодно
  }
}
```